# Speech REST API - maxnbest parameter ignored

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

The optional parameter [maxnbest](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#optional-parameters) seems to be always ignored and the response always contains a single result (at least for fr-Fr language).
Is there a way/workaround to have multiple results?

Answer (score 1):

The results you receive depend on the audio sent.  If the engine can confidently find a result it wont send extra results back.

Comment: Are you sure? I ve been using it for a while now and I never received more than one result, no matter the audio nor the confidence

Comment: There have not been any changes made to this parameter.  I will have our Developers investigate this further.  Thank you for bringing this concern to our attention.

Comment: Hi Ray, do you have more info?